# mixed partial derivative of function of $C^{(2)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

ILet $f$ be of class $C^{(2)}$ and let $\displaystyle F(x,y)=f(x,xy)$, then I want to find the mixed partial derivative $\displaystyle F_{12}$.

Here I am letting
$g^{1}(x,y)=x$ and $g^{2}(x,y)=xy$. 
Using the chain rule I get,
$$F_{1}=f_{1}g_{1}^{1}+f_{2}g_{1}^{2}=f_{1}\cdot 1+f_{2}\cdot y.$$
Then I don't know how to find $F_{12}$? Please make a suggestion!

Comment: The sub/superscript notation used here is unnecessarily confusing.

Answer (score 1):

By $F_{12}$, do you mean $\displaystyle{{\partial^2 F\over \partial x\,\partial y}}$?

If so, take the partial with respect to $y$.

Comment: Maybe, you mean $\dfrac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}$?

Comment: Thanks, misplaced ^2. Fixed now.